# Simulate Hardware Level Keystrokes Through XBee

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have been working on a project and I have been trying to simulate keyboard strokes on my laptop at a hardware level without actually pressing down my laptop keys. That is straight through the I/O registers. Rather than going through software, I had a few Xbee's lying around and figured I would make a wireless keyboard of sorts. My question is whether or not data sent through the ZigBee framework will be interpreted at a hardware level by my laptop? I figured it must be somewhat similar to my Logitech Unifying receiver which I know gets interpreted at the hardware level. Also, is there a way that I can see the code generated both by a physical keypress on my laptop vs the code sent by an Xbee module? Would there be an additional value present in the code sent by the Xbee to symbolize that it wasn't an physical keypress on the laptop? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The XBee connects to your laptop as an asynchronous serial port.  I suspect that your keyboard connects via USB, Bluetooth or some other wireless dongle.  Even the built-in keyboard is probably USB as well, and should appear as an HID (human interface device).

You'd need to write a program on the laptop to receive the serial data and somehow pass it on to the OS so it appears as keyboard input.